# Why does Pandas read_CSV return TextFileReader even if iterator = False?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, timeit

Environment:
python           : 3.7.10.final.0,
python-bits      : 64,
OS               : Windows, 64GB mem,
OS-release       : 10,
Version          : 10.0.19041,
**pandas           : 1.2.4**

I have a very simple read statement after a simple print statement and conditional to check that I do want to read the whole file...

`%timeit csvDataFrame = pd.read_csv(fc.selected, sep=",", header='infer', na_values ='?', skiprows=csvSkipRows, dtype=desiDtypesDict, comment = '#', iterator=False)`

where fc.selected is the full path to a CSV of ~2 million rows (524MB on disk); csvSkipRows = [] and desiDtypesDict is a dict of types for the columns in the dataset.

CSV reading works works fine if I also add e.g. `chunksize = 10`, and iterate on the result so I am confident about the arguments, but when I try to read the whole file in at once

- %timeit tells me that it took ~6s/loop and that there were 7 loops
- csvDataFrame is not a dataframe but a TextFileReader

even if iterator = False
In this environment, Python generally has no problem accessing huge amounts of memory so:

**Why is this happening, and how to I read the CSV in all at once?**

Answer (score 0):

**Why is it happening?** %timeit has interacted with pandas oddly*

**How do you read the CSV all at once?** Omit the %timeit

A fresh kernel and a minor modification later and we identify that the problem is due to putting %timeit before the read_csv.

Remove it and the total time is the same but a single dataframe is now returned, 2684511 rows × 31 columns, as expected and desired.

Recommendation: always test with minimal code before inferring that there really is a problem.

* *exactly* what the interaction is I don't know... maybe somebody else does.

The full cell code was:

```
# Read all at once.
print(readCSVAllAtOnce)

if readCSVAllAtOnce:
    %timeit csvDataFrame = pd.read_csv(fc.selected, sep=",", header='infer', na_values ='?', skiprows=csvSkipRows, dtype=desiDtypesDict, comment = '#', iterator=False, chunksize=None)
```